# Supplying power to my camp with a generator

Tags: electrical

I'm building a remote camp and will wire it for lights and receptacles (only). I plan to back-feed power from a generator to a small sub panel which has 6 breakers. Should I run 220v from generator to sub panel or 110v? The stove and frig are propane.

Comment: Why are you using such a tiny subpanel?

Comment: Because the camp will only have lights and receptacles. Can not have pressurized water system thus, no inside plumbing, water heater, etc.  Heating with wood.  It's in a very remote part of Maine albeit on a beautiful lake.

Comment: You're definitely allowed to use a bigger one. Not doing so is often the path of regret.  Becuase in many instances you can only use half your breaker spaces, and can't use double-stuff breakers. For instance a 6-space will only support one 240V load and will put all the 120V loads on one leg, unevenly loading the generator (proper) and making excessive heat.

Answer (score 1):

If your gen hasvoltage fluctuation better than regoular incandescent 220V output, it's better (for gen. health) to use both phases and balance the circuits across them, if your gen is 110 only... you havn't asked the question.
I suggest not to use electric hot-water also but to run it on LPG .
If you consider keeping the generator running all the time, electric fridge is better then LPG-fired.

For lighting I suggest to go for LEDs, now it's cheap and tolerate voltage variations better than a regular incandescent/halogen. Also will give you more light-hours without having to refuel or more light for the same power.

Also suggest to install breaker (on outlet circuits) that, as total, won't drain more than 80% power capacity of your unit (remember you have also  lighting). So if your gen is 5,5kW/220V 2-Ph, your 'general breaker' shouden't be bigger than 5500/220 = 40A and 'outlet' breakers souldn't be bigger than: (40 x 80%)/2 = 16A for each 'leg' if you have 2 outlets' circuit

Note: protections are kept 'low' (compared to standard) to avoid overloading the generator.

Edit: if you don't have a 'utility' power connection to your panel, you can connect the generator directly as 'main' supply, without the need for an interlock (as the generator will be the only source for your power).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Gen is a 6k with 110/220v capability, and electric start. Camp will/does not have indoor plumbing, hot water htr etc. So, I don't need a lot of circuits thus my reason for a 6-breaker panel. I ran a (110v) line to an outside receptacle with the intent to use it to back feed power to the panel. But looking at the panel, I would only get power to half the breakers (?) So, now I'm thinking I need to run a 3-wire (220v) line from the receptacle to the panel in order to power all six breakers (?) I do intend to use LED lights throughout the camp

Comment: Yes: back-feeding from an outlet will only power half of your system. I suggest you to add a 'secondary inlet' to feed you panel, with a mutual exclusion between main (utility) switch and generator. ABSOLUTELY DON'T DO MALE-MALE CABLE OR YOU RISK ELECTROCUTION. Also using an (existing) outlet isn't a good idea because you don't know if wires are thick enough to sustain the whole load.  In the end you'll have a 'male' to be connected to the generator coming from your main panel, a mechanical device that 'inibhits' you from having on both utility and generator line on at same time.

Comment: this video explains quite well how to install the gen. and the interlock.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SLd3a5SrGk

Comment: They make the right receptacle for what you want to do, it is called an **inlet** and has a male (prongy) plug where you would normally expect a socket.  You just plug a normal extension cord with its male end into the generator, female end into the inlet. Safe as houses, provided you don't have utility power to interlock.  That "can't use half your spaces" problem you ran into is one of the reasons we say bigger panel.

Comment: I still don't understand how a larger panel will help me. My question is; do I just run a 10/2 line from the "inlet" to the panel or a 10/3?  Seems to me if I run a 2 wire, I'm only going to get power to one side (3 breakers) of the panel. But if I run a 3 wire, I can power both sides (all 6 breakers)? If my assumption is correct, will I need an "inlet" configured for the 220v side of the generator?

Comment: No, you don't need a larger panel (it may be useful if you plan to upgrade the structure, but at the moment it won't give you anything more ). For now you need a 3 conductor cable (L1+L2+N) and an inlet. Suggest you a very minimum of 6mm^2 conductors but 10mm^2 would be better for a no longer than 30m main feed line. For a 100m line, get a 25 mm^2 cable. If you plan to get a bigger generator (15 kW-60A) install 70mm^2 line for a 100m long line  or 25mm^2 for a 30m long one

Answer (score 0):

When you state back feed , is this panel fed by a utility also? If the generator is the only source of power it is a feeder. and in this case 6 breakers is plenty big enough as your generator can't push that much. If you are feeding a panel that is fed from another source you need an interlock or transfer switch to prevent backfeeding the utility and protecting your generator. You should utilize 220 v this will be better for the generator, once you have all your loads connected you should verify that's the loads are balanced or close on each leg. This will use the least amount of fuel and be easier on the generator a few years ago I helped a older gentleman with his home generator that he had set up with everything on 1 leg he thought this would save fuel in fact after I split things up and balanced the loads he said he was using about 30% less fuel than he was using. He also said he had less flickers when he turned on other loads or when his refer turned on.